PostgreSQL 12.17 Extract element from JSON Array
Good morning
PostgreSQL version 12.17
I have a column called "design" which contains JSON array data.
column
The JSON stored within this column is formatted as follows:
{
    "objectVersion": 0,
    "design": [
        {
            "setNumber": true,
            "objectVersion": 0,
            "type": "RULE_PART",
            "number": 0,
            "operator": "EQUAL",
            "left": {
                "objectVersion": 0,
                "type": "RESOLVED",
                "value": "94068ff0-e73e-4f99-9f66-7025bf14ffb4.Ce6188690-7495-4bd0-a9c6-91ef98acb64a",
                "resolverType": "FORM",
                "_type": "RulePartOperand"
            },
            "right": {
                "objectVersion": 0,
                "type": "LITERAL",
                "value": "N",
                "resolverType": null,
                "_type": "RulePartOperand"
            },
            "combine": "AND",
            "subParts": [],
            "_type": "RulePart"
        },
        {
            "setNumber": true,
            "objectVersion": 0,
            "type": "RULE_PART",
            "number": 1,
            "operator": "EQUAL",
            "left": {
                "objectVersion": 0,
                "type": "RESOLVED",
                "value": "94068ff0-e73e-4f99-9f66-7025bf14ffb4.C292d1bbe-cfc0-4736-a164-70882714cbf0",
                "resolverType": "FORM",
                "_type": "RulePartOperand"
            },
            "right": {
                "objectVersion": 0,
                "type": "LITERAL",
                "value": "Y",
                "resolverType": null,
                "_type": "RulePartOperand"
            },
            "combine": "OR",
            "subParts": [],
            "_type": "RulePart"
        }
    ]
}

I would like to retrieve the data associated with "Value" from "left":
value
When I use the following (json_array_elements):
select json_array_elements(design::json -> 'design') 
from public.rule_definition where  definition_id = 'some id'

I have:
Elements
However, I'm struggling to understand how to retrieve the individual elements, IE, the "value" field.
As you may have guessed, I've not worked with PostgreSQL before and as such, would really appreciate any insight you may have that will help me move forward.
Thanks all.

Go further down the path the same way you got from the top level down into design, using the same -> operator: demo
select json_array_elements(design::json -> 'design')->'left'->'value'
from public.rule_definition where  definition_id = 'some id'




?column?




"94068ff0-e73e-4f99-9f66-7025bf14ffb4.Ce6188690-7495-4bd0-a9c6-91ef98acb64a"


"94068ff0-e73e-4f99-9f66-7025bf14ffb4.C292d1bbe-cfc0-4736-a164-70882714cbf0"



PostgreSQL 12 also supports JSONPath expressions if you use jsonb instead of json:
select jsonb_path_query(design::jsonb, '$.design[*].left.value')
from public.rule_definition where  definition_id = 'some id'

Note that both of these yield a json/jsonb, hence the quotes in the value. If you want to retrieve a text, and possibly cast that to some other type, you need to switch the last -> to ->>:
select json_array_elements(design::json -> 'design')->'left'->>'value'
from public.rule_definition where  definition_id = 'some id';

And in case of jsonb_path_query(), you'll need to unwrap the jsonb with a #>>'{}':
select jsonb_path_query(design::jsonb, '$.design[*].left.value')#>>'{}'
from public.rule_definition where  definition_id = 'some id'


Hi Zegarek. Fantastic, and many thanks for your timely support.
